# Using pagination in Doctrine2/Symfony2 without Doctrine paginator extension

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine2 for a project that might get a lot of traffic and I'm welling to do some pagination in a search page and that only fetch 5 results per page
So is there a good way for doing this without the need to use the doctrine extension and keeping the ORM abstraction layer? I mean I don't want to write any form of dql queries and keep my code in this format:

```
 $repo= $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getEntityManager()
                    ->getRepository('AcmeOfficeBundle:Project');
        $list=$repo->findBy(array('PROJ_private' => "0"));
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Doctrine 2.2 [ships with a paginator](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html). However, it *does* require you to write DQL queries.

If you insist on not writing any DQL, you can start by looking at the Doctrine EntityRepository class; specifically, [the findBy() method](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L177). It has optional parameters for limit and offset, so you can try something like this (using your example as a baseline):

```
$num_pages = x; // some calculation of what page you're currently on
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AcmeOfficeBundle:Project');
$list = $repo->findBy(
    array('PROJ_private' => "0"), //search criteria, as usual
    array(/* orderBy criteria if needed, else empty array */),
    5, // limit
    5 * ($num_pages - 1) // offset
);
```

Comment: Thx for the part on Doctrine 2.2 shipping with a Paginator, didn't know that.

Comment: How would I get the total number of pages for a result set? Do I need to run a separate findBy() without the last two parameters to get the total number of results and then calculate it myself? That seems inefficient, but I'm not sure if there's a more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

In Doctrine ORM 2.3 you can also utilize `Criteria` along with `matching` on the entity repository. Which now (as of 2.5) works with nToMany relationships.

This helps when your query requires another comparison other than equals or when paginating a OneToMany collection of another entity.

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > 0 ? $_GET['page'] : 1);
$limit = 20;
$offset = ($limit * ($page - 1));
$criteria = \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria::create()
    ->setMaxResults($limit)
    ->setFirstResult($offset);
$expr = $criteria->expr();
$user = $em->getRepository('AcmeOfficeBundle:Project')
    ->matching($criteria->where($expr->gt('PROJ_private', 0)));
$total_records = $user->count();
```

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections

Answer (score 0):

A good option that avoids writing DQL is to operate on collections using Pagerfanta

https://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta

```
use Pagerfanta\Adapter\DoctrineCollectionAdapter;
$user = $em->find("App\DoctrineORM\User", 1);
$adapter = new DoctrineCollectionAdapter($user->getGroups());
```